# Hyperlink not working in Django

Tags: django

I tried my best to hack this. But decided to get help. I guess that I am overlooking something that makes the application to freeze.

The Problem: after clicking the link in **pcq_select.html**, the url changes to "pcq/list/1" or pcq/list/2" as per the selection made. But the page does not move to the expected **pcq_list.html**. In simple terms, after clicking the link no change happens to the page. Please help.

Note: All products are listed properly in **pcq_select.html** and when I mouse over, it shows the correct p.id values.

**pcq_select.html**:

```
Select the Product:
<ol>
   {% for p in object_list %}
   <li>
   <a class="editbutton" href="{% url "pcq_list" p.id %}">{{ p.productname }}</a>
   </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^pcq/list/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', views.pcq_list, name='pcq_list')
```

**view.py**

```
def pcq_list(request, product_id):
    c = Pcq.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = c
    return render_to_response('maps/pcq/pcq_list.html', data)
```

**pcq_list.html**

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Component Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            {% for pcq in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                    <td>{{ pcq.component }}</td>
                    <td>{{ pcq.quantity }}</td>
                    <td><a class="editbutton" href="{% url "pcq_edit" pcq.id %}">edit</a></td>
                    <td><a class="deletebutton" href="{% url "pcq_delete" pcq.id %}">delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
</table>
```

**models.py**

```
class Pcq(models.Model):
product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
component = models.ForeignKey(Component)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.product.productname
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems not problem with django. If you can open /pcq/list/1 directly - there is a problem in  client side. Maybe there is catch of link click in your javascript code.

Comment: I am not using JavaScript in this application. And when I try to open using /pcq/list/2 directly, the problem exists.

Comment: So show your urls.py file. Maybe definition of "pcq_select" url is wrong and catch all possible urls.